# Iptables Prevent Flooding

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, tcp, iptables, ddos

I know you can limit number of connections per ip, per time interval etc, but what I am wanting is amount of data.

I'm hosting a socket server, and I thought rather than making it do the processing to check for flooding - offload it to the firewall. I know you can guard against syn flooding attacks, like mentioned here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html

For example:

```
# Limit the number of incoming tcp connections
# Interface 0 incoming syn-flood protection
iptables -N syn_flood
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j syn_flood
iptables -A syn_flood -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 3 -j RETURN
iptables -A syn_flood -j DROP
#Limiting the incoming icmp ping request:
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit  1/s --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-prefix PING-DROP:
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

I'm not sure what iptables can do, so the question is a bit vague. But since web-sockets use tcp I should be able to limit number of bytes per second. And flag connections exceeding that limit or just drop them, whatever.

I can't seem to find a good reference on this, as they are all about tracking connections etc, not data transfer. Does anyone know of a good reference or how to do this? Is iptables not a good firewall for this? if not what is?

Comment: By "*data*", do you include Ethernet frames and their headers?

Comment: @user2284570 yes I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel-side firewall is the fastest and the most secure software solution *(difficult to kill the kernel isn't it?)*. Using it have also the advantage to use the hardware firewall found on some network controllers.
Iptables is the primary tool for controlling it, but there are [many others frontends](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firewalls#iptables) with easier syntax.

If you want to configure easier, you should use this :[image: screenshot of traffic shaping configuration].
Keep in mind tracking byte count for each IP can use lot of memory.
In your case I would install [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/), which is developed by the same team of iptables :

```
#create ipset for accounting with default lifetime 300 secs
ipset create IP_QUOTA_SET hash:ip timeout 300 counters

#create separated rule chain
iptables --new-chain PER_IP_QOUTING

#send packets to chain
iptables -t filter -A INPUT \
  -i <in-iface> --dst <ip>  \
  -p tcp --dport <dstport>  \
  -j PER_IP_QUOTING

#if ip doesn't exist in the set, add it
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING    \
  -m set ! --match-set IP_QUOTA_SET src \
  -j SET --add-set IP_QUOTA_SET src --timeout 300

#if packet exists in the set, check bytes
#if byte counter > quota then drop packet
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING    \
  -m set --match-set IP_QUOTA_SET src   \
  --bytes-gr 1000 -j DROP

#pass other packets (for debug purpose)
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING \
  -j RETURN
```

In this case you can check the list and edit it by ipset command.
To show current list with counters and timeouts :`ipset list IP_QUOTA_SET`.

**STRONG NOTE :** *iptables is Linux specific and is available since linux 2.4. The kernel implementation along the userspace tools did change in 2.0 and 2.2 previously.

The 3.13 version introduced a [new change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nftables) which will replace ipset; arptables; ebtables; ip6tables, and iptables with a single tool.

As with previous versions, their will be a transition period where frontends like vuurmuur will remain compatible with the kernel, but don't expect to use iptables in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try the iptable command mark together with tc (traffic-shaping):http://www.amiryan.org/2009/02/16/traffic-shaping-under-linux-with-tc-and-iptables/.